# S3 client is not being built on WebLogic 12c

Tags: java, amazon-s3, weblogic12c, aws-sdk-java

There is an application deployed on a weblogic that periodically uploads a file to the cloud using the s3 protocol. Used AWS SDK for Java 1.x.
Part of the code

```
public AmazonS3 connect() {
   AWSCredentials cr = new BasicAWSCredentials(k, s);
   AmazonS3ClientBuilder standard = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard();
   standard.withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(cr));
   standard.withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(s, r));
   AmazonS3 s3client = standard.build();

   return s3client;
}
```

But when I deploy&start the application (as war package) on WebLogic 12c, it freezes on line with *build()* in 6 line (I determined it by leaving an entry in the log on each line). No exception, no log message with error.
Building&runing this code in IntellijIdea local, without deployment on the WebLogic 12c, working excellent!
I'm new to developing an application for the server, I can't see the logs.

What could be the problem?

Comment: At first take several thread dumps when your application is freezing to see exactly where it is stucked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the **aws java sdk** version, 1.12.56 was used, the problem disappeared when using 1.11.430.